# How to limit the words input in Quill Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, quill

I'm following the example of codepen [building a word counter modul](https://codepen.io/quill/pen/wWOdXZ?editors=1010) in addition of counting, **I need to limit the input to 30 words, so the user can't write any more**. I don't know where to implement what I need. I think I can use something like splice( begin, end).

These two are doing the count words stuff:

```
calculate() {
   let text = this.quill.getText();
   if (this.options.unit === 'word') {
     text = text.trim();
     return text.length > 0 ? text.split(/\s+/).length : 0
   } else {
    return text.length;
   }
 }

 update() {
   var length = this.calculate();
   var label = this.options.unit;
   if (length !== 1) {
     label += 's';
   } 
 this.container.innerHTML = length + ' ' + label;
 }
```

I don't know if I have to add a new method or modify one of this two. Something like:

```
limitWords() {
  let text = this.quill.getText();
  if (text.length > 30) {
     text = text.splice(0, 30);
  }
  return text.length;
}
```

This obviously fails, any guidance would be very appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @maioman I got a more close approach of what I need, by doing the following I can "limit" the words to 30.

**The problem**

If I keep typing the previews words disappear and than I get a undefined in the input field:

```
update() {
var length = this.calculate();
if (length > 30) { 
  this.restrict();
}
var label = this.options.unit;
if (length !== 1) {
  label += 's';
}
 this.container.innerHTML = length + ' ' + label;
}

restrict() {
  let text = this.quill.getText();
  text = text.replace(/\s+.+/);
  this.quill.setText(text);
  this.update()
 }
```

**What I tried:**

```
let text = this.quill.getText().slice(0, 30);
```

This doesn't throws an undefined but it does not work.

Comment: what behaviour would you like to have when you reach 30 words?

Comment: just don't be able to input or write more words, I need to restrict these to only 30 words.